# To make comments move with cells in a filtered table on excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table with filters created using VBA with several comments. All comments are important and there is a huge amount of data on it. I am trying to find a way to avoid error messages when filters are applied. I know that if I loop trough a entire column and set
`Comment.Shape.Placement = xlMoveAndSize` by cells it should work, but is there a way to select the entire range like this?

```
masterSheet.Columns(columnExtension).Comment.Shape.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
```

I also tried in this context:

```
'Final formating -----------------------------------------------

masterSheet.Activate
masterSheet.Columns(columnExtension).Font.Size = 12
masterSheet.Columns(columnExtension).Font.Bold = True
masterSheet.Columns(columnExtension).NumberFormat = "0"
masterSheet.Columns(columnExtension).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells _
(xlCellTypeComments).Comment.Shape.Placement = xlMoveAndSize

masterSheet.Columns.AutoFit
```

Answer (score 2):

I could not find a way to do all at once as I was looking for...so I just wrote the loop, it works, but...

```
'// Change each comment to "move and size with cells"
For Each cellComment In ActiveSheet.Comments
     cellComment.Shape.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
Next cellComment
```

It might be useful for someone..

Answer (score 0):

Using `SpecialCells` range object also worked for me, iterating over only the cells which contain comments.

```
Sub Test2()
Dim rng As Range
Dim cl As Range

Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments)
For Each cl In rng.Cells
    cl.Comment.Shape.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: That was what I did, it works it is just not what I was looking for... well.. thanks anyway